# Не удается установить изображение как background для оберточного div через props в React

Tags: reactjs, изображения, background

Всем привет!

Недавно начал изучать React и столкнулся с проблемой: не получается установить background для компонента - картинки из массива, используя props, для оберточного div с классом "pictureWrap".

Пробовал через 'styled-components', но получается выводить только одно изображение используя import. Реализовать background через props удалось только для вложенного тэга img, но цель - установить фон для всего div элемента.

Буду рад вашей помощи или совету!)

Сам компонент:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/GridComponentStyle.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';

class GridComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="pictureWrap">

                <img src={this.props.image} alt="pics" width="100%" />

                <div className="marginTop">
                    <a href={this.props.link}>
                        <h3>{this.props.title}</h3>
                        <p>{this.props.text}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default GridComponent;
```

как часть более крупного компонента:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/main.css';
import GridComponent from './gridComponent';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            pictures: [
                require("../img/cat1.jpg"),
                require("../img/cat2.jpg"),
                require("../img/cat3.jpg"),
                require("../img/cat4.jpg"),
                require("../img/cat5.jpg"),
                require("../img/cat6.jpg")
            ]
        }
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <main>
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <div className="home">

                        <GridComponent title="Title name 1" text="Some text." image={this.state.pictures[0]}/>
                        <GridComponent title="Title name 2" text="Some text." image={this.state.pictures[1]}/>
                        <GridComponent title="Title name 3" text="Some text." image={this.state.pictures[2]}/>
                        <GridComponent title="Title name 4" text="Some text." image={this.state.pictures[3]}/>
                        <GridComponent title="Title name 5" text="Some text." image={this.state.pictures[4]}/>
                        <GridComponent title="Title name 6" text="Some text." image={this.state.pictures[5]}/>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

и само приложение:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './components/header';
import Main from './components/main';
import Footer from './components/footer';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <Header />
        <Main />
        <Footer />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно импортировать картинки в React с помощью `import`. При этом в переменных у Вас получается путь, который обрабатывается сборщиком *(в случае с **create-react-app** это webpack)*.

Детальнее можете почитать в [документации](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files)

*./src/Main.js*

```
import React from "react";

import GridComponent from './gridComponent';
import Cat1ImgSrc from "../img/cat1.jpg";
import Cat2ImgSrc from "../img/cat2.jpg";
import Cat3ImgSrc from "../img/cat3.jpg";
import '../css/main.css';

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      pictures: [
        Cat1ImgSrc,
        Cat2ImgSrc,
        Cat3ImgSrc
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { pictures } = this.state;
    return ( 
      <main>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="home">
            {
              pictures.map((imgSrc, i) => <GridComponent title={`Title name ${i+1}`} text="Some text." image={imgSrc}/>)
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

*./src/gridComponent.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/GridComponentStyle.css';

class GridComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { image, link, title, text } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="pictureWrap">

        <img src={image} alt="pics" width="100%" />

        <div className="marginTop">
          <a href={link}>
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <p>{text}</p>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GridComponent;
```

P.S.
 1. Не называйте файлы компонентов с маленькой буквы.
 2. Используйте [деструктуризацию](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring) чтобы очистить свой код от лишних повторений `this.props`/`this.state`

Comment: Спасибо, огромное! Все заработало!)